# Remove #(hash/pound) from URL with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a url of my site for example such as mysite.com/pagename//#page_2. I want to remove the '//#' from respective url and want my URL mysite.com/pagename/page_2 how I can do it?

Comment: You can use sql update query to replace mysite.com/pagename//#page_2 with mysite.com/pagename/page_2

Comment: You simply cannot. The server cannot read or modify URL fragments

Comment: @Phil - Can he not use SQL query to do this? Like sql query which  we use to change all pages link when move site from one server to another..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress - remove #! characters from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967670/wordpress-remove-characters-from-url)

Comment: why do you have a double / and a hash in there? that is not wordpress default, you've modified the rewrite rules in the first place so undo the changes :), by default wordpress uses the url that is similar to what you are looking for: mysite.com/pagename/page/2